# Product Method Overloading( It is the same person that asked last time)

Tags: java, overloading

I was working on this problem and could not do it and was not sure if I even understood what method overloading really is. Can anyone explain what it is (since  the resources I found online were not really good) , and possibly fix the mistakes I've made?

The question is : overload the product method to allow for multiplying together other types of values:

two doubles
an int and a double
a double and an int
three ints
three doubles

I'm getting errors saying : 
- Possible lossy conversion from double to int (line 13 , 16 , 19)
- Product 2 / Product 3 is already defined
- Method is expecting type int, int and type int,int,int was given(line 17)

```
   public class Product extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        int intValue = 5;
        double doubleValue = 2.5;

        int product1 = product(intValue, intValue);
        System.out.println(product1);

        // Use method overloading to define methods 
        // for each of the following method calls

        double product2 =  product(doubleValue , doubleValue);
        System.out.println(product1);

        int product3 = product(intValue * intValue, intValue);
        System.out.println(product1);

        double product4 = product(intValue, doubleValue);
        System.out.println(product1);

        double product5 = product(doubleValue, intValue);
        System.out.println(product1);

        double product6 = product(doubleValue *doubleValue, doubleValue);
        System.out.println(product1);
    }

    public int product(int one, int two)
    {
        return one * two;
    }

}
```

Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method overloading is just when you want to name the method the same withing the same class, but the signature is different.

When I say signature is different it might be, the parameter types are different such as :

```
public int multiplyProduct(int one, int two) {}

//We are overloading right here as we already defined a multiplyProduct above

public int multiplyProduct(long one, long two){}
```

Or it can be just the number of parameters are different:

```
public int multiplyProduct(long one, long two, long three){}
```

In your example above you had a class called Product:

```
class Product {

  public int multiplyProduct(int one, int two) {}

  public int multiplyProduct(int one, long two) {}

  public int multiplyProduct(long one, long two){}

  public int multiplyProduct(long one, long two, long three){}

  public int multiplyProduct(double one, double two) {}

}
```

So as you now to call the methods you do:

```
//To call the multiply(int one, int two)
new Product().multiply(1,1)

//To call the multiply(int one, long two)
new Product().multiply(1,1L)

//To call the multiply(long one, long two, long three)
new Product().multiply(1L,1L,1L)

//To call the multiply(double one, double two)
new Product().multiply(1.0,1.0)
```

Regarding the error you just need to create a new method that accept two double and return a double:

```
public void run() {

    int intValue = 5;
    double doubleValue = 2.5;

    int product1 = product(intValue, intValue);
    System.out.println(product1);

    // Use method overloading to define methods
    // for each of the following method calls
    double product2 = product(doubleValue, doubleValue);
    System.out.println(product1);

    int product3 = product(intValue * intValue, intValue);
    System.out.println(product1);

    double product4 = product(intValue, doubleValue);
    System.out.println(product1);

    double product5 = product(doubleValue, intValue);
    System.out.println(product1);

    double product6 = product(doubleValue * doubleValue, doubleValue);
    System.out.println(product1);
}

public int product(int one, int two) {
    return one * two;
}

public double product(double one, double two) {
    return one * two;
}
```

Comment: So basically, if I want to overload  int product1 = product(intValue, intValue);  , I would have to write int product 1  = product (doubleValue,doubleValue)??

Comment: Kind of, I will edit my example for it to be clear with an example!

Comment: Thank you, Can you explain what "possible lossy conversion from double to int"?    double product2 = product(doubleValue , doubleValue); this is the coding i've written and it is showing me this error msg.

Comment: So that error means you are trying to cast a double to an int. The precision will be lost/truncated eg: 2.1 will become 2. 

I am guessing the product(doubleValue, doubleValue) is returning an int, but you are trying to assign it to a double = product2.

Make sure the return value of product(doubleValue, doubleValue) is a double.

Eg: 

public double multiplyProduct(double one, double two) {}

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it properly. Can you just give me one line of example coding using my coding? (I am pretty sure I can do it myself after) Thank you so much for helping me youre the best

Comment: Can you post full example of the code, and comment where the error is happening.

Comment: Yes I've just edited the question with the coding I have. The error I am getting is "Incompatible types, possible lossy conversion from double to int" for product 2 ,4,5 and 6. Also, I am getting error saying "method is expecting type int,int but int,int,int was given (line 22)" and "method is expecting type int,int but double,double,double was given"(line 25) but line 22 and 25 is just blank line without any coding?

Comment: I have updated my example, you just need to create a new method that accepts two double and return a double

Comment: Thanks youre the best.

Comment: Could you vote it as the answer :)

Comment: yes, @Ian, just did thank you so much man appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Method overloading is just when you want to name the method the same withing the same class, but the signature is different.
Different signature means either the parameters are of different types OR
parameters are given in different order OR number of parameters are different.

Given code shows all types of method overloading:

```
    public class Product extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run(){

        int intValue = 5;
        double doubleValue = 2.5;

        int product1 = product(intValue, intValue);
        System.out.println(product1);

        // Use method overloading to define methods 
        // for each of the following method calls

        double product1 = product(doubleValue, doubleValue);
        System.out.println(product1);

        int product3 = product(intValue, intValue, intValue);
        System.out.println(product3);

        double product2 = product(intValue, doubleValue);
        System.out.println(product2);

        double product2 = product(doubleValue, intValue);
        System.out.println(product2);

        double product3 = product(doubleValue, doubleValue, doubleValue);
        System.out.println(product3);


        public int product(int one, int two)
        {
            return one * two;
        }

        //different types of parameters

        public double product(double one, double two)
        {
            return one * two;
        }

        //different number of parameters

        public int product(int one, int two, int three)
        {
            return one * two * three;
        }

        public double product(int one, double two)
        {
            return one * two;
        }

        //different order of parameters

        public double product(double one, int two)
        {
            return one * two;
        }

        public double product(double one, double two, double three)
        {
            return one * two * three;
        }
    }
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: okay so I now get the idea what the method overloading is, but I just cannot  find what the problem is with my coding.. Can you give me one example? Thank you

Comment: OK, so see the code below :

Comment: double Bill(int item, int price){
        double total = item * price;
        return total;
    }
    
    double Bill(int item, double price){
        double total = item * price;
        return total;
    }
    /* we are overloading Bill function
       by changing the number of parameter */
    
    double Bill(int item, double price, double tax){
        double total = item * price * tax;
        return total;
    }

Comment: /* we are overloading Bill function
       by changing the order of parameter */
    
    double Bill(double price, double tax,int item){
        double total = item * price * tax;
        return total;
    }

Comment: oh right alright thanks